# addClass() to items in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, addclass

I am trying to use jQuery's addClass() to add the class "picbox_selected" to the items in the array features, which have id numbers corresponding to the index of items in the array config. I tried the following code but it is not working.

```
var leftHandShape = features['Left Hand Shape']
for (i = 0; i < config.HandShapes.length; i++) {
    var handName = config.HandShapes[i].Name;
    if (leftHandShape == handName) {
        var idNo = '.picbox id' + i
        $(idNo).addClass('picbox_selected')
    }
}
```

I tried this as well but it's not working either. Please help!

```
var leftHandShape = features['Left Hand Shape']
for (i = 0; i < config.HandShapes.length; i++) {
    var handName = config.HandShapes[i].Name;
    if (leftHandShape == handName) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.picbox id' + i).addClass('picbox_selected')
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement.  State the behavior you are actually getting.

Comment: the class is not getting added

Comment: Pickbox id does not work. You cannot have space in class and ids

Comment: @Jkike: Suggest something that does work.

Comment: Ok... first suggestion: $('.pickbox id') will search for an element with class pickbox ... what is id then? Remove the whitespace from classname first.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you have this:

```
$('.picbox id' + i).addClass('picbox_selected')
```

Lets take a look at the selector `'.picbox id'`:

1. Find all elements with class `picbox`
2. Find all `<id>` elements.

Woah! Wait a second! You **REALLY** want that? Or you meant `'.picbox #id'`?

---

Look at `'.picbox #id'` we have:

1. Find all elements with class `picbox`
2. Find all elements with `id="id"`.

Is this what you were trying to do?

Comment: I have class names called id0, id1, id2, etc. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @sleepycow Then instead of `#id`, use `.id` which should do it

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do it for all of them?

You could use a simple javascript for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < features.count; i++){
  var item = features[i];
  item.className = "picbox_selected";
};
```

Comment: I want to add the class for all items in the array feature, but not the array config. I might try the className approach though!